# In Maxima, how to check whether a series converges?

Tags: maxima, convergence

I would like to create a function that returns true precisely if a series diverges to infinity.

Unfortunately it seems that Maxima throws an error if a series diverges. I loaded the package simplify_sum and I hoped that `simplify_sum(sum(1/n,n,1,inf))` would return `inf`, but it returns

```
sum: sum is divergent.
#0: simplify_sum(expr='sum(1/n,n,1,inf))
-- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

How can I check whether a series diverges to infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized this cannot be done as this is an undecidable problem.

Comment: At some point maxima is telling you it's diverging. Is there a way to catch the error ?